# How to make so Random Number (under 50 milliseconds) wont repeat twice

Tags: c++, variables, random

I'm making script and it generates random numbers in milliseconds (Range 20-100), let's say it generated delays : 30, 40 , 42 (All < (less than) 50)

Now I want to make it so 4th delay cant be again less than 50, I tried this:

I tried using for loop, but my when i use this code script doesn't work at all anymore / it won't toggle or anything.

Just imagine you made script and it generates random numbers from 20-100 and you dont want 4 in row delays that are less than 50, what would you do? Thanks.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 4;)
        {

            // Total Delay aka delay1+delay2
            if (totaldelay < 50)
            {
                i++;
            }

            // Should make totaldelay > 50
            if (i == 3)
            {
                delay1 = RandomInt(75, 105);
            }

            // Reset to 0 so it checks from 0 again
            if (total > 50)
            {
                i = 0;
            }





        }
```

Comment: A simple way to generate random numbers in a range, is to simply create a container with all the number in the range, and then [shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) the container. To get the random number, just get each and every element from the container.

Comment: this seems to be okay code, except while being inefficient. What's the problem?

Comment: And please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). That will tell you that you need to describe what problems you have with the [mcve] that you show us. Edit your question to include all the crucial details and information.

Comment: You could read something about how to produce numbers that looks random. This is my favourite, but there are probably others:
http://mostlymangling.blogspot.com/2019/01/

Comment: Why are you making four random number instead of one that is guaranteed to be larger than `50`? Or, simple solution, just add 50 and you're guaranteed to be over that value and still have it be random.

Comment: Then keep a rolling sum of the four last numbers, and if a sum is less than `50` add `50` (or some other random number that's guaranteed to make it larger than `50`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you don't want four consecutive numbers to be all less than 50. You can achieve this by simply keeping a count and adjusting your behaviour so that you generate a different number if the previous three were all less than 50.

If you're looking for a standalone C++ function to do that (give you one random number per call, with your specific added limitations), you can use something like:

```
int getMyRand() {
    // Keep track of how many consecutive under-50s already done.
    // Careful in multi-threaded code, may need thread-local instead.

    static int consecUnder50 = 0;
    int number;

    // If last three were all < 50, force next one to be >= 50.

    if (consecUnder50 == 3) {
        number = rand() % 51 + 50;  // 50-100 (inclusive).
    } else {
        number = rand() % 81 + 20;  // 20-100 (inclusive).
    }

    // If less, record it, otherwise restart count.

    if (number < 50) {
        ++consecUnder50;
    } else {
        consecUnder50 = 0;
    }

    // Give caller the number.

    return number;
}
```

---

Don't forget to seed the random number generator before using this, and be aware that C++ has better random number generators, although `rand()` is usually fine unless you're a statistician or cryptographer :-)

Comment: I adopted your thing to my code but still doesnt work… any ways of contacting you so you check my whole code? I have did seed thing already few days ago this is only thing left

Comment: @Rall0ck, that's not really how SO is meant to work - in any case, I'm off to bed :-) I'd suggest asking another question, posting the code you've written. That way, you'll have the hordes of SO answerers on your problem while I catch some shut-eye. In the *incredibly* unlikely case that they can't help you before I wake, I'll have a look tomorrow :-)